# create multiple columns from list of values of another column

Tags: python, parsing, pandas, split, dataframe

I have the dataframe that looks like:

```
Groupe       Id   MotherName   FatherName    Field
Advanced    56    Laure         James        English-107,Economics, Management, History, Philosophy
Middle      11    Ann           Nicolas      Web-development, Java-2
Advanced    6     Helen         Franc        Literature, English-2
Beginner    43    Laure         James        Mathematics, History, Philosophy, Literature
Middle      14    Naomi         Franc        Java-2, Management, English-107
```

For farther work with the data, I need to split the `Field` column, and replace it with multiple columns that will look like:

```
Id English-107 Economics Management History Web-development Java-2 Literature English-2 Mathematics Philosophy
56     1         1          1           1           0          0       0             0          0         1
11     0         0          0           0           1           1      0             0            0          0
```

So these columns could be append to the initial dataframe. I don't know how to make it, because just basic splitting like

```
pd.DataFrame(df.Field.str.split(',',1).tolist())
```

doesn't resolve my probleme, because I need the columns based not just on the position in the list, but based on every unique value in the list. Have you any idea how I can approach it?

Comment: Are you after `df.cata.str.split(',',expand=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
print pd.concat([df['Id'], df['Field'].str.get_dummies(sep=",")], axis=1)
   Id  Economics  English-107  English-2  History  Java-2  Literature  \
0  56          1            1          0        1       0           0   
1  11          0            0          0        0       1           0   
2   6          0            0          1        0       0           1   
3  43          0            0          0        1       0           1   
4  14          0            1          0        0       1           0   

   Management  Mathematics  Philosophy  Web-development  
0           1            0           1                0  
1           0            0           0                1  
2           0            0           0                0  
3           0            1           1                0  
4           1            0           0                0
```

If you need count values, you can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) (I add one string `Economics` for testing):

```
df1 = df['Field'].str.split(',',expand=True).stack()
                                            .groupby(level=0)
                                            .value_counts()
                                            .reset_index()
df1.columns=['a','b','c']
print df1.pivot_table(index='a',columns='b',values='c').fillna(0)
b  Economics  English-107  English-2  History  Java-2  Literature  Management  \
a                                                                               
0          2            1          0        1       0           0           1   
1          0            0          0        0       1           0           0   
2          0            0          1        0       0           1           0   
3          0            0          0        1       0           1           0   
4          0            1          0        0       1           0           1   

b  Mathematics  Philosophy  Web-development  
a                                            
0            0           1                0  
1            0           0                1  
2            0           0                0  
3            1           1                0  
4            0           0                0
```

Comment: cool solution, didn't know `get_dummies` had a separator parameter, i've only used on single-valued coluumns